# Snapping with polgon drawing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, snapping, map-drawing

I am drawing a polygon with the drawing function within ArcGIS 10.1.  Is there a way to snap orthographically at 90 degrees while using the polygon draw command.[image]

I added a picture of what i would like to do but as you can see the callout is not drawn at 90 degrees.

Comment: could you please illustrate what you need or explain why the existing tools (e.g. ctrl+E or deflection) do not help ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to try using a balloon call out for a text box if you are not editing a feature then. It is nicely hidden below a couple of menus but is pretty useful:

Once you have drawn the rectangle open the properties, select 'edit symbol' and follow the buttons in the image below to turn on the 'Balloon Callout'. When you've finished editing you can position the text box and the start of the callout on your figure as needed.

[image: Balloon callout]

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s60000000z000000

Comment: +1, this is a simpler solution than manually drawing the callout (and worrying about orthogonality)